# Hide LiveActivityIntent Button from Shortcuts App

Tags: ios, swiftui, sirishortcuts, widgetliveactivity

I'm using LiveActivityIntent in the following way to add interactive buttons to my Live Activity:

```
struct Test: LiveActivityIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Test"

    public init() { }

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        return .result()
    }
}
```

This works as expected. However, the LiveActivityIntent also shows up in the Shortcuts app. That does not make sense because the buttons should not be user-configurable. How can I hide the button intents from the Shortcuts app?

[image]